# Apache Nifi || InvokeHttp processor displaying error

Tags: apache-nifi

InvokeHttp processor is displaying error, Please help in understanding the below error:

[image]

Also PFB invokehttp processor:

[image]

[image]

Comment: you got a response from api. and it says that header 'Authorization' is required. you have to provide `basic auth username/password` parameters or what you have to authorize your api call...

Comment: I am already passing the same but still getting the same error.

Comment: then this question is not to `apache-nifi` group but to `wso2` server

Comment: @daggett: It worked as initially i was passing the username/password in predefined parameter, after using user defined parameter it worked. thanks